# Pausing JavaScript when Chrome tab is not active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I want the JavaScript engine of Chrome to pause when its tab is not active in order to save power(specifically a laptop's power).
Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Listen for blur and focus events to disable and enable, receptively, any script.

Comment: Thanks for information and fixing my english!

Answer (score 2):

Listen to `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` and create a check in your loop. I'm guessing your using a loop of some kind.

See [Window.onblur on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onblur).

Comment: Thanks. I want to pause any script even if it is managed not by me, but it's good information.

Comment: In that case, you could for example create an `alert()` on blur, that way all scripts will have to wait until someone click "OK".

Comment: An `alert();` would be extremely obnoxious for a user.

Comment: I used a running ms counter to calculate ms diffs in my loop. When `onblur` occurred, I would stop the loop altogether. When `onfocus` occurred, I would immediately set the previous ms to the current ms and then resume the loop. I also increment a running "actual" (unpaused) total ms counter alongside the diff variable, in case I need to e.g. do something every X ms. This all works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the easiest way to pause JavaScript written by *other* people is to write a a Chrome extension using
[contentSettings.javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#property-javascript):

```
chrome.contentSettings.javascript = allow; // Run JavaScript
chrome.contentSettings.javascript = block; // Don't run JavaScript.
```

It sounds like you would use the [onActivated event in the chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) to detect when the user changes the active tab.

Perhaps you might also pause JavaScript in *every* tab when the machine is idle, using the [chrome.idle api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/idle).

Perhaps that is how other Chrome extensions hibernate tabs, such as

The Great Suspender
(see ["SuperUser: Automatically hibernate Google Chrome tabs"](https://superuser.com/questions/553822/automatically-hibernate-google-chrome-tabs))
and
TooManyTabs
(see ["10 Useful Chrome Extensions For Efficient Tabs Management"](http://www.maketecheasier.com/10-chrome-extensions-for-efficient-tabs-management/)).